# Oracle: SQL query on view returning inconsistent result set

Tags: sql, oracle, view

I have a Oracle view (e.g. v_myview_0) which is created by joining another six views (v_myview_1, v_myview_2, v_myview_3, v_myview_4, v_myview_5, v_myview_6). Each of these 6 views are created using tables on different schemas. The data in these tables is updated by a micro-service based application.

I have written another query on v_myview_0 with appropriate WHERE CLAUSE and expect this query returns a single row.

**Problem:** Usually the query returns expected result (single row). However sometimes for a span of few minutes, the query alternately returns a single row and multiple rows (mostly any no. of rows between 7 to 11 rows). Even though I run the query repeatedly every second, the result keep toggling between single row and multiple rows. And then suddenly it will start returning only single row again.

I carefully reviewed all the joins and underlying data but failed to get the cause.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: even if we new the views, the problem is obviuos, at some time in your process, you have multiple ows that are joined, and only after some time the data gets cleared by updatind some values, so you have to take a step back and make a visual paln when whic table gets updated, and you will find somewhere between the seconds you are runnig  you last view to fast

Comment: One possibility: data changes to tables in one schema are committed (and therefore "visible" to your query), while data in tables in another schema is being changed but the changes have not been committed yet (so these changes aren't "visible" to your query, and instead the old data is still used). Try to compare "when that happens" (the odd behavior you reported) vs. "when the data is updated" by your application, to see if this possible explanation is something you might want to investigate further.

Comment: Thanks for revert. If its data inconsistency / integrity / atomicity issue, then what can be the reason to have correct result for every alternate execution?

Comment: Some updates may affect the result of joins, while other updates don't. It all depends on which specific columns are updated in each table. Uncommitted changes to non-join columns may not result in a different number of rows in the output, but the data may still be invalid (inconsistent: reflecting changes in some columns but not in others).

Comment: One possible way to narrow down the point in a query where you have different results is to gather **actual** execution plans of both the cases (correct and incorrect) with `dbms_xplan.display_cursor(format=>'ALL ALLSTATS LAST')`. Then compare A-rows column and find the difference between single-row plan and multi-row plan

Comment: Thank you for reverts and suggestions. When next time it occurs I will check and compare it.